# How do load a partial view with its own form action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have three tabs on the form but I have sep elements on the form however I have a partial view loaded in between the main elements which has its own form

Obv I could have the one form tag to contain the main elements but how would I handle my sep view in this case as at present the main form tag would overide it

**Edit 2** 
The main problem I am having is that when I load the partial view the main modal is not being filled as I have not told it to go to a controller to perform some linq my main question is how do i do this.

```
<div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="nav-tabs-custom">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#productInfo" data-toggle="tab">Product Info</a></li>
            <li><a href="#images" data-toggle="tab">Product Images</a></li>
            <li><a href="#seo" data-toggle="tab">Seo</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">


          <div class="active tab-pane" id="productInfo">

            <!-- Horizontal Form -->
             <div class="box box-info">
              <div class="box-header with-border">
                 <h3 class="box-title">Horizontal Form</h3>
               </div>
              <!-- /.box-header -->
               <!-- form start -->

               <div class="box-body">

              <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
              <div class="form-group">
               <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" asp-for="ProductName" class="form-control" id="productName">
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="SKU" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Sku</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input asp-for="SKU" class="form-control" />
                                        <span asp-validation-for="SKU" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label asp-for="LongDescription" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                                        <textarea id="editor1" class="form-control"></textarea>
                                        <span asp-validation-for="LongDescription" class="text-danger"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>






                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        <div class="input-group">

                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i></span>
                                                <input type="text" asp-for="OldPrice" placeholder="Price" class="form-control">

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>

                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                                        <div class="input-group">
                                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-gbp"></i></span>
                                            <input type="text" asp-for="OldPrice" placeholder="Old Price" class="form-control">

                                        </div>
                                        <!-- /input-group -->
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                </div>



    </form>

                        </div>
                        <!-- /.tab-pane -->
                    </div>

                </div>


                <div class="tab-pane" id="images">

                    Product Images
                    @await Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicture", Model)


                </div>

                <div class="tab-pane" id="seo">

</div>

</div>
```

This is my partial view which is loaded from the above.

```
@model solitude.models.Models.ViewModels.ProductImageVm 
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@

@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml")




    <div class="form-group">

        <form asp-controller="Products" asp-action="FileUpload" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form">



            <input asp-for="Title" />
            <input asp-for="ProductId" type="hidden" />
            <input asp-for="Image" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>



    </div>
```

Comment: @CodingYoshi can you proide an email with that please thanks

Comment: You are posting the forms to different actions, for example, one is being posted to `FileUpload`. So whats the issue?

Comment: @CodingYoshi the partial layout is not loading any data even though ProductsImages has one record in it I perusme that is because I have not given it a controller.

Comment: @CodingYoshi please see edit 2 above for more details on my problem

Comment: It would help to see a version of your model that has enough to demonstrate how you're model-binding, and the same with your controller. Your question needs to contain enough for someone to recreate what you're seeing without needing to guess.

Comment: You're not passing any data to the `ProductPicturesList` partial. Did you mean to type `@Html.PartialAsync("_ProductPicturesList.cshtml", Model)`?